# Removing duplicate rows (based on values from multiple columns) from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
+--------------+------------+-------------------+------------+
| id           | DATA_ID    |   SourceID        | DateAdded  |
+--------------+------------+-------------------+------------+
|           1  | 304019032  | 1                 |  2018-01-20|
|           2  | 345583556  | 1                 |  2018-01-21|
|           3  | 299951717  | 3                 |  2018-01-23|
|           4  | 304019032  | 2                 |  2018-01-24|
|           5  | 298519282  | 2                 |  2018-01-24|
|           6  | 299951717  | 3                 |  2018-01-27|
|           7  | 345583556  | 1                 |  2018-01-27|
+--------------+------------+-------------------+------------+
```

I'm trying to delete duplicate rows that have the same DATA_ID and SourceID, leaving the row with the most recent date.

Comment: Please show which rows you would like to delete.  I am guessing you just want to delete rows 1 and 3 based on your description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server, I like to use `row_number()` and an updatable CTE for this:

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (partition by sourceid, dataid order by dateadded desc) as seqnum
      from t
     )
delete from todelete
    where seqnum > 1;
```

This will work even when `sourceid`/`dataid` is `NULL` (which is probably not the case for you).   It also does not assume that `dateadded` and `id` are mutually increasing (although that might be a reasonable assumption).

Comment: +1 - dateadded could get out of whack with ID if imported from another system and they wanted to retain the original date.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff do you mean `delete from todelete
    where seqnum > 1`?

Comment: @AlexKudryashev . . . LOL.  Yes.  That would be the more appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from your_table
where id not in 
(
  select max(id)
  from your_table
  group by data_id, sourceID
)
```