# How to delete duplicate rows that have same data except one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, duplicates

I am trying to delete duplicate rows but leaving recent updated rows.

Here is illustration of my dataset:

[image]

I am trying to delete two rows that are older data (in this case 11/19's - highlighted in yellow).

This is dataset in text:

| employee | ID | punch_start | punch_end | punch_hours | date_load |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Doe | 276567 | Sep 30 2023 2:50PM | Oct 1 2023 6:00AM | 15.16666667 | 11/19/23 2:45 PM |
| Jane Doe | 140037 | Sep 30 2023 10:00PM | Oct 1 2023 7:05AM | 9.083333333 | 11/19/23 2:45 PM |
| John Doe | 276567 | Sep 30 2023 2:50PM | Oct 1 2023 6:00AM | 15.16666667 | 11/20/23 2:45 PM |
| Jane Doe | 140037 | Sep 30 2023 10:00PM | Oct 1 2023 7:05AM | 9.083333333 | 11/20/23 2:45 PM |

I tried with this code (based one this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48481387/removing-duplicate-rows-based-on-values-from-multiple-columns-from-sql-server)):

```
with todelete as 
(
    select  
      ,[employee]
      ,[ID]
      ,[punch_start]
      ,[punch_end]
      ,[punch_hours]
      ,row_number() over

      (
       partition by 
       [employee]
      ,[ID]
      ,[punch_start]
      ,[punch_end]
      ,[punch_hours]
      order by [date_load] desc) as seqnum
      from  [dbo].[dataset]
     )
    select * from todelete where seqnum > 1;
    delete from todelete where seqnum > 1;
```

But the result (on Select *) is:

[image]

How do we modify the code to distinguish/only select rows that have older [date_load]?

Comment: What datatype is `date_load`? What happens if you change your `order by [date_load] desc` to sort `asc` instead?

Comment: @esqew date type is "datetime" in SQL. If I change to asc, the data result (select *) is same. I did not execute deletion yet.

Comment: Please don't use images, use tabular text (as you done for one table - just do it for all).

Comment: but why do you think your result is incorrect? your query looks good to me, unless date_load isn't really datetime. you can append the date_load to your select query to see the values of those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the DELETE in SQL Server has enough syntax to support this, but I generally do MERGE here.

https://dbfiddle.uk/_5PR_82q

```
merge into [dbo].[dataset] as tgt using (
    select *  
      from (
              select  
                  ,[employee]
                  ,[ID]
                  ,[punch_start]
                  ,[punch_end]
                  ,[punch_hours]
                  ,[date_load]
                  ,row_number() over

                  (
                   partition by 
                   [employee]
                  ,[ID]
                  ,[punch_start]
                  ,[punch_end]
                  ,[punch_hours]
                  order by [date_load] desc) as seqnum
              from  [dbo].[dataset]
            ) ranked
     where seqnum > 1
     ) as mrg
    ON (
       tgt.employee = mrg.employee and
       tgt.id = mrg.id and
       tgt.punch_start = mrg.punch_start and
       tgt.punch_end = mrg.punch_end and
       tgt.punch_hours = mrg.punch_hours and 
       tgt.date_load = mrg.date_load
       )
    WHEN MATCHED THEN DELETE;
```

Also, maybe SQL Server does some magic that I'm not aware of. But in your original question

```
delete from todelete where seqnum > 1;
```

Probably will just fail for syntax. Because todelete is just a cte defined in a totally separate query.

Comment: How do I see the result (do the select *) before deletion?

Comment: @Java Just run the query block that sits between "using (" and ") as mrg"

Comment: @Java And it's also always good practice to take a backup before running any delete you aren't 100% confident in.

Comment: I now understand how to do the "select..". Thanks. My next question is: Do we keep the "tgt.date_load = mrg.date_load" since we are comparing with different dates?

Comment: @Java Yes, because the inner USING clause gets you the records you want to delete. So you need all the fields to uniquely join. If you didn't have that you'd end up deleting any record with duplicates regardless of the date.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. It worked.

Comment: @Java Woah. That's no good. Always have a production back-out plan when you get there. So you need to be more selective in the delete than described in your original question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256011/discussion-between-error-2646-and-java).